# How to handle the situation of multiple json parsed for the same route?

Tags: json, rust, rust-axum

I have a requirement that I need to handle a request with multiple ways in a same HTTP route, according to the JSON in the body.

There is a total different JSON object in route `root("/")`

like

- url_verification

```json
{
  "challenge": "b397743d-51c9-40c2-a529-098fd2ff7b4a",
  "token": "1p37CgbHAxiVCmzPhY8epfT2rV7YBSQi",
  "type": "url_verification"
}
```

- receive message

```json
{
    "schema": "2.0",
    "header": { 
        "event_id": "f7984f25108f8137722bb63cee927e66",
        "token": "066zT6pS4QCbgj5Do145GfDbbagCHGgF",
        "create_time": "1603977298000000",
        "event_type": "contact.user_group.created_v3",
        "tenant_key": "xxxxxxx",
        "app_id": "cli_xxxxxxxx",
    },
    "event":{
    }
}
```

Here is my Rust code:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct UrlVerification {
    challenge: String,
    token: String,
    r#type: String,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct UrlVerificationResp {
    challenge: String,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    pretty_env_logger::init();

    let app = Router::new()
        .route("/", post(url_verification));
        // .route("/", post(msg_recv));  // Overlapping method route

    let addr = SocketAddr::from(([127,0,0,1], 3000));
    axum::Server::bind(&addr)
        .serve(app.into_make_service())
        .await
        .unwrap();
}


// can not receive a parsed json as a params
async fn url_verification(Json(verified): Json<UrlVerification>) -> impl IntoResponse {
    (StatusCode::OK, Json(UrlVerificationResp {
        challenge: verified.challenge
    }))
}
```

So in Axum, how to solve this kind of problem elegantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`serde` can have ["untagged enums"](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#untagged), where it will try to deserialize into the first variant it can. You can use this to represent data types that may be one of a number of formats.

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum RootRequest {
    UrlVerification(UrlVerification),
    RecieveMessage(ReceiveMessage),
}
```

With this, you can have a single route that deserializes the body to this untagged enum type, and delegates to different implementations based on what the actual received request is:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // ...

    let app = Router::new()
        .route("/", post(root_route));

    // ...
}

async fn root_route(Json(body): Json<RootRequest>) -> Response {
    match body {
        RootRequest::UrlVerification(verified) => {
            url_verification(verified).await.into_response()
        }

        RootRequest::ReceiveMessage(msg) => {
            msg_recv(msg).await.into_response()
        }
    }
}

async fn url_verification(verified: UrlVerification) -> impl IntoResponse {
    // ...
}

async fn recv_msg(msg: ReceiveMessage) -> impl IntoResponse {
    // ...
}
```